# How to configure jms-queue on Wildfly 24 service using ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I am trying to configure a simple JMS message queue on WildFly 24. I am starting the server using `standalone-full.xml`. I see following configuration:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <remote-connector name="artemis" socket-binding="messaging-activemq">
        <param name="use-nio" value="true"/>
        <param name="use-nio-global-worker-pool" value="true"/>
    </remote-connector>
    <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="artemis" transaction="xa" user="guest" password="guest" />
</subsystem>
```

I have followed [the documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/24/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging) and added the following configuration to both `standalone-full.xml` and `standalone-full-ha.xml` configurations:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        <http-connector name="http-connector"
                        socket-binding="http"
                        endpoint="http-acceptor" />
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput"
                        socket-binding="http"
                        endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay"
                   value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm"
                         server-id="0"/>
      <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory"
                            connectors="in-vm"
                            entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" />
      <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra"
                            transaction="xa"
                            connectors="in-vm"
                            entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
       <jms-queue name="testQueue"
               entries="jms/queue/test java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test" />
   </server>
</subsystem>
```

Server fail to start with following exception:

```
WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default' are not available: org.wildfly.security.legacy-security-domain.other; There are no known registration points which can provide this capability.
```

Is the WildFly documentation is old? Am I missing something here? Please let me know the correct way of configuring the jms-queue in WildFly 24

Answer (score 1):

By default, if no security domain (deprecated) or elytron domain is defined, the security domain is the legacy 'other'. You need to configure such a security domain to one of yours or restore the legacy 'other' one.

Comment: If i understand correctly without defining a security domain we can not define a new Server configuration for activemq subsystem? Since i am using this my localhost deployments i don't want any security domain defined for the activemq subsystem, is the deault activemq configuration comes with standaline-full.xml is good enough? do we need any additional config needed for default messaging? please post the required configuration to configure the security domain

Comment: The standalone-full.xml provides such a configuration.

Comment: I wonder if you can show an example of the final configuration. I'm stuck at the exact same problem.

Comment: I had the exact same error and I added this excerpt into the server element: <security elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>. I'm still not convinced it's the correct elytron-domain for me, but I get a step further.